# calculate and return number of days in a week

Tags: php

how to calculate number of days in a week? for example 1st week in January 2014 has 4 days, so the function will return 4.

googled this, no answers to my need.

Comment: Make an effort and post your attempt and where you are stuck. Answers are not spoon fed.

Comment: thanks @EvanCarslake. i have no idea about it, is there any built in method for this or should i start writing the function from 0? if there is no built in method, then i am going to find a hint and write it myself.

Comment: yes there is no function that outright does this, you'll gonna have to write it yourself first. Consider using the `DateTime` class of PHP

Comment: They all have 7. Unless you mean something different than you are asking.

Comment: This question is not well specified. Give concrete examples of input and expected output, so we can know what it is you're looking for.

Comment: @JakeParis : for example, in January 2014, there are 5 weeks, first week starting from January 1st 2014, which is wednesday, so for this week it will return 4 days.

Comment: So you want to start with the first day of the month, get the weekday of that date, and then calc how many days left until Saturday.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking here. Can you add more details to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "January 1 2014 Sunday";
echo date("z", strtotime($str));
```

Output - 4

ps: works only for the first week of January of any year as follows from question.

pps: this is for 1st week of any month

```
$str = "February 1 2014";
echo date("z", strtotime($str . " Sunday")) - date("z", strtotime($str));
```

and for the last week

```
$str = "February 2014";
echo date("z", strtotime("last day of " . $str)) -
     date("z", strtotime("last monday of " . $str));
```

Comment: aw, it's close to my need..tried `February 1 2014 Sunday` and it return 32 LOL. thanks anyway

Comment: @DarielPratama do you want to know number of days in a first week of any month? show specific examples.

Comment: yes, exactly number of days in first week, and last week actually.

Comment: @DarielPratama added for the last week too.